# Something wrong with creating adjacency matrix

Tags: c

it asks two questions at once,why?
here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i,j;
    int n;
    int adjmatrix[n][n];
    char ans;
    printf("How many vertices?");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            printf("Are vertex %d and %d adjacent?",i,j);
            scanf("%c",&ans);
            if (ans=='Y' || ans=='y')
            {
                adjmatrix[i][j]=1;
            }
            else adjmatrix[i][j]=0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance！

[image]

Comment: `int adjmatrix[n][n];` UB here. You must initialize a variable before using.

Comment: `scanf("%d",&n);` leaves the newline in the input buffer for the first `scanf("%c",&ans);` to read.

Comment: Consider reading http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html before using `scanf`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But how to solve this problem with scanf?

Comment: "how to solve this problem with scanf?" Why use a weak solution?  Go with `fgets()`.

Answer (score 0):

You're right. The output is weird.

Your problem is `scanf`. Use `scanf("%2c", ans);`. Helped me.

But even then, i had the problem that the loops are not iterated
correctly.

**Explanation:**

The reason was the matrix. The matrix is not allocating any memory because its size if variable.
Therefore by setting an entry of the matrix to 1, this influences the variable `j`.

**Solution:**

You need to solve the problem to dynamically allocate memory.
Have a look at:

- https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx9b.html
- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamically-allocate-2d-array-c/